# PHP code to display CSV file with option to remove each line

Tags: php, csv, fopen, file-handling

I was able to put together a code to display a CSV file containing a list of emails (each line is an email address) for a newsletter group. I am struggling adding a "remove" function  in front of each of those email addresses in case the email is no longer valid (or the user no longer wants to receive emails). Here is what I have:

function my_magic_function(){

```
$file = TEMPLATEPATH."/user_list.csv";

if (file_exists($file )) {

    $handle = fopen($file , "r+");

    echo '<p><a href="/wp-content/themes/summer/user_list.csv"> Download the CSV File</a></p>';

    $contents = fread($handle, filesize($file));

    $emails = explode(',',$contents);

    for ($x=0; $x<count($emails) -1; $x++){

        echo $emails[$x]."; (remove)<br />";

    }

    fclose($handle);

}else{

    echo "empty";

}
```

}

What am I missing? How do I make that "(remove)" delete that specific email address (or line)?

Thanks

Comment: That is not how you parse a CSV file!!! Use [`fgetcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)!

Comment: That's not a CSV file at all. It's a comma separated list of email addresses. `mailparse_rfc822_parse_addresses()` might be even more applicable. At the very least look into `file_get_contents()` over `fopen/fread/fclose`.

Answer (score 1):

Output a delete link:

```
 echo "<a href=delete.php?mail=$email[x]>delete</a> ";
```

In that delete script read in the email list in an array again. Use [`array_search()`](http://php.net/array_search) to find the entry, and then do a simple `unset()` on the returned key. Afterwards write the file back.

```
 $emails = str_getcsv(file_get_contents("emails.txt"));

 $del_index = array_search($emails, $_GET["mail"]);
 unset($emails[ $del_index ]);

 file_put_contents("email.txt", join(", ", $emails));
```

Also look into using `foreach` instead of a `for` loop.